# Realm query sometimes return no data

Tags: realm

I am implementing a process to store hundreds of thousands of records and retrieve them by realm query.

The simplified code is as follows

- Realm Object

```
final class Friend: Object {
    @objc dynamic var number: Int64 = 0
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    convenience init(number: Int64, label: String) {
        self.init()
        self.number = number
        self.label = label
    }

    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "number"
    }
}

extension Realm {
    static var `default`: Realm {
        get {
            do {
                let realm = try Realm(configuration: RealmConstants.configuration)
                return realm
            } catch {
                return self.default
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- RealmClient class

```
struct RealmClient {
    static func save(_ list: [Friend],
                              completion: @escaping (Result<Void, Error>) -> Void) {

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            autoreleasepool {
                do {
                    let realm = Realm.default
                    try realm.write {

                        realm.add(list)
                        completion(.success(()))
                    }
                } catch {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- DataStore class (shared file with Call directory extension target)

```
class DataStore {

  let realm = realm
  
  init(realm: Realm.default) {
     self.realm = realm
  }

  var recordcounts: Int {
     return realm.objects(Friend.self).count
  }
}
```

However, sometimes the realm query returns 0 records.

- Query results

```
RealmClient.save(friendList) -> friendList is hundreds of thousands of data fetched from server

let dataStore = DataStore()
dataStore.recordcounts -> sometimes return 0
```

So I have implemented refreshing the realm instance, but it doesn't help.

Like this.
`realm.refresh()`

- Question

I want to be able to always get the data in a query.
How can I implement stable data using a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm writes are transactional - the transaction is a list of read and write operations that Realm treats as a single indivisible operation.

The reads and writes within the closure {} following the write are part of the transaction; the data is not committed until all of those complete. Transactions are also all or nothing - either all operations complete or none.

Most importantly for this case, transactions are synchronous so adding a callback within the transaction is going to present intermittent results.

Move the callback outside the write transaction

```
try realm.write {
   realm.add(list)
}
completion(.success(()))
```

It can be illustrated by how we used to write realm transactions:

```
realm.beginWrite()
write some data

// Commit the write transaction to make this data available to other threads
try! realm.commitWrite() <- data is not valid until after it's been committed

//data has been committed
```